# httplistener connection keep alive possible?

Tags: c#, httplistener

Is there a way to force c# HttpListener to use keep alive connection if client is sending keep alive connection header, it looks like when you send reply connection is automatically closed, then client is creating another socket connection and that is slow part, can be problem if you are requesting from client data every 50,100ms, tried to put keep alive connection header in response but it is not working

Thanks

Comment: How did you determine this is the case?

Comment: fiddler and apache bench, example for ab ab.exe -k -c 100 -n 100000 -l -H "Accept: application/json"                                                       Complete requests:      100000
Failed requests:        0
Keep-Alive requests:    0